# Test suite for ECMAScript 5 support

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, ecmascript-5

Does anyone know if there exists a test suite (written in QUnit, for example) that tests for ECMAScript 5 support?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most "official" test suite is probably [ECMAScript Test262](http://test262.ecmascript.org/), which is being developed by members of Ecma TC39.

There's also the open-sourced [ECMAScript 5 Conformance Suite](http://es5conform.codeplex.com/) developed by Microsoft, and Google's [Sputnik](http://code.google.com/p/sputniktests/), which tests "all aspects" of ECMAScript 3 and parts of ECMAScript 5. Both of those suites are included as part of ECMAScript Test262.

If you just want to test for basic support (e.g. existence of new functions, not whether they behave correctly in every case), there's the [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), which includes a column for the browser you're using.

Comment: MS's testsuite is included in Test262 too. However, note this is not just testing for support: it is testing for conformance to the spec, so a large number of the tests are all about edge-cases that authors mostly probably don't care about.

Comment: @gsnedders: Thanks, I figured it probably would be, but I wasn't sure. That's also a good point about strict conformance vs. usable support. I'll add a link for that.